# Finding it extremely difficult to get through with my Masters thesis. Stuck with a mediocre thesis

Tags: thesis, masters, emotional-responses

I am very close to finishing my masters and am finding it extremely difficult to get through with my thesis. Although my topic is relevant and interesting, nobody, including my supervisor is able to guide me well. All my thesis reviews until now have gone really bad because they think I am not doing anything fancy.

I have discussed this with my guide and am not receiving any help. I feel my guide is not much experienced in this area of research. I am currently in the middle of my thesis where I cannot change my topic. I feel stuck and demotivated. I feel all the effort that I am putting in is going down the drain.

I feel sad and miserable all the time. All those students who didn't perform well earlier are putting up their best work now and are appreciated while I am stuck here with my unappealing work. I really want to take some time off this work but cant due to the  tight schedule of my reviews. I already had serious anxiety issues and this is making it worse.

I really want to know if any of you faced similar issues and how you overcame it. Any suggestions on how to recover are welcome.

Comment: What do you mean by "reviews"?

Comment: Periodical assessment by a panel of faculties

Comment: Have you talked about that to the student office? You might be now too late, because you are towards the end of your project. It is very hard to work on a field where the supervisor cannot guide you. Any chance to switch topics/supervisors? Keep in mind that choice of a good topic may also be a lot of luck, but definitely the supervisor must be on board.

Comment: Yeah changing topic would just worsen my situation at this stage. We dint have a lot of options for selecting a supervisor. So I just chose the one who whose willing to guide me.

Comment: That's bad. Try to identify where you are stuck, write it on a list, and find out where you can move, and try to focus your progress there. Do it on paper, this will help clearing your mind, trust me.

Answer (score 4):

First, I suggest that you talk to a professional counselor about your frustration and how to cope with it. If you don't do that you could wind up in worse shape than you are.

However, "mediocre thesis" is probably a misstatement. You are stuck and you aren't getting the feedback that will help you advance. Your advisor isn't providing it and may not be able to. However, there might be other faculty that you can speak with that will have some ideas.

Many students at about your position find themselves in a bit of a burnout situation, having worked hard for a long time without a break. I went through that and also once worked with an unhelpful advisor. I had to change institutions to break the cycle, but, had I been braver, I could have shortened my process by insisting on a change of advisors. Later I found that things like regular (aerobic) exercise helped me maintain a more sensible work flow.

For the thesis work itself, you need someone, probably a faculty member who can get you through whatever technical block you are facing. You say the topic is relevant and interesting. But you may be missing some important insight. Doing the same things over and over may not lead you to that. It may be a small thing or not, but try to get some assistance. If you can't change advisors, and they can't help, look elsewhere.

But first, deal with the emotional/personal issues.

Comment: Thank you. I shall try to seek help.

Comment: Universities often have a counseling office or one dedicated to student assistance of various kinds.